# VSCode восстанавливает формат

Tags: visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте! Есть кусок кода, я хочу его немного изменить(просто перенести на другую строку), но при сохранении CTRL+S, текст возвращается в прежнее состояние. Это глюк VSCode?

https://youtu.be/QrdvcWkDj3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках по умолчанию стоит   `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`, возможно изменили эту настройку.